# Unrecognized selector sent to instance for setDetailModal

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm getting the following debug message when trying to click a segueway in my app.

```
"SmokingPig[13840:c07] -[UIViewController setDetailModal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75836c0"
```

This is my TableViewController.m File(or the part I think is messed up at least)

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
    DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    int row = [myIndexPath row];
    detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row], _Description[row]];
}
```

This is my DetailViewController.h File
    #import

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DetailModal;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segue points to an instance of generic `UIViewController`, not your `DetailViewController`.  If the segue is described in IB, select the view controller on the destination end of the segue, then use the identity inspector (third inspector from the left) and make certain the custom class is set to DetailViewController.

You're probably getting a warning on this line, too:

```
DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];
```

Fix that with a cast:

```
DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```